# What will happen if one column mentioned as primary key in DB and other column as primary key in mapping structure in infomratica

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter, informatica-cloud, informatica-data-integration-hub

What will happen if one column mentioned as primary key in DB and other column as primary key in mapping structure in informatica Powercenter or IICS.

Comment: Why would you ever do this? If you want to know, why not just try it?

Comment: it is an interview question I got. I can't play with the Informatica in the org level.

Comment: If the data/mapping doesn't cause a conflict with the actual data then nothing will happen. If it does conflict then it will either error or cause unexpected behaviour

Answer (score 0):

It would not create an issue, as long as it is for reading the data.

But, if we are going to write the data in the target(using different keys) then Informatica would perform the record operation(I/U/D) on the basis of the key defined in Informatica.